# creating 3 pairs made from +6 objects where each pair has unique & unrepeated objects

Tags: java, for-loop, combinatorics

I have a list of possible objects that could be 6 or more in length (+6 photons/gammas) and I need to make 3 pairs from this list (3 pions). These pairs need to all have unique objects, and no gamma can be re-used once it is in a pair.

For e.g. if pion1 is made from gamma1 (in the code: ig1) and gamma2 (ig2), then pions2 & pions3 have to be made from all possible combinations of gammas3,4,5,6,etc (it is possible to have more than 6 gammas, but I only care about 3 total pions), and so on.

I attempted to next several for loops in the following manner:

```
int n_g = 8; // n_g >= 6
boolean hasDVPi0P = false;
for (int ig1 = 0; ig1 < n_g-5 && !hasDVPi0P ; ig1++) {
    for (int ig2 = ig1+1; ig2 < n_g-4 && !hasDVPi0P ; ig2++) {
        for (int ig3 = ig2+1; ig3 < n_g-3 && !hasDVPi0P ; ig3++) {
            for (int ig4 = ig3+1; ig4 < n_g-2 && !hasDVPi0P ; ig4++) {
                for (int ig5 = ig4+1; ig5 < n_g-1 && !hasDVPi0P ; ig5++) {
                    for (int ig6 = ig5+1; ig6 < n_g && !hasDVPi0P ; ig6++) {
                        System.out.println("(" + ig1 + "," + ig2 + ") , (" + ig3 + "," + ig4 + ") , (" + ig5 + "," + ig6 + ")");
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

which gets me the following output:

```
(0,1) , (2,3) , (4,5)
(0,1) , (2,3) , (4,6)
(0,1) , (2,3) , (4,7)
(0,1) , (2,3) , (5,6)
(0,1) , (2,3) , (5,7)
(0,1) , (2,3) , (6,7)
(0,1) , (2,4) , (5,6)
(0,1) , (2,4) , (5,7)
(0,1) , (2,4) , (6,7)
(0,1) , (2,5) , (6,7)
(0,1) , (3,4) , (5,6)
(0,1) , (3,4) , (5,7)
(0,1) , (3,4) , (6,7)
(0,1) , (3,5) , (6,7)
(0,1) , (4,5) , (6,7)
(0,2) , (3,4) , (5,6)
(0,2) , (3,4) , (5,7)
(0,2) , (3,4) , (6,7)
(0,2) , (3,5) , (6,7)
(0,2) , (4,5) , (6,7)
(0,3) , (4,5) , (6,7)
(1,2) , (3,4) , (5,6)
(1,2) , (3,4) , (5,7)
(1,2) , (3,4) , (6,7)
(1,2) , (3,5) , (6,7)
(1,2) , (4,5) , (6,7)
(1,3) , (4,5) , (6,7)
(2,3) , (4,5) , (6,7)
```

Which I *initially* thought was correct *until* I checked n_g=6, which gets me

```
(0,1) , (2,3) , (4,5)
```

Which is clearly the wrong output. I tried to find all unique possible pairs for 6 gamma in the following way:

```
n_g=6;
for(int ig1 = 0; ig1 < n_g-1; ig1++) {
    for(int ig2 = ig1+1; ig2 < n_g; ig2++) {
        System.out.print("(" + ig1 + "," + ig2 + ") ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

which gives me

```
(0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5) 
(1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5) 
(2,3) (2,4) (2,5) 
(3,4) (3,5) 
(4,5)
```

Does anyone have any ideas for how I would edit the first code segment with 6 for loops to get 3 pairs of pions where, if a gamma is used for 1 pion, it is not repeated again? Order in the pair *does* matter, and that means if a pair is (0,1) then pair (1,0) is different and not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wanted to see a version with the nested for loops, and a version that considers (0,1) the same as (1,0). This is a slightly simpler version than the answer with the two classes, and I thought someone might benefit if they ever came around looking for a way to make pairs in a slightly different way.

```
int n_g = 6;
boolean hasDVPi0P = false;
for (int ig1 = 0; ig1 < n_g && !hasDVPi0P ; ig1++) {
    for (int ig2 = 0; ig2 < n_g && !hasDVPi0P ; ig2++) {
        for (int ig3 = 0; ig3 < n_g && !hasDVPi0P ; ig3++) {
            for (int ig4 = 0; ig4 < n_g && !hasDVPi0P ; ig4++) {
                for (int ig5 = 0; ig5 < n_g && !hasDVPi0P ; ig5++) {
                    for (int ig6 = 0; ig6 < n_g && !hasDVPi0P ; ig6++) {
                        if( true
                            && ig1<ig2 && ig3<ig4 && ig5<ig6 // different photons in each pair
                            && ig1<ig3 && ig1<ig5 && ig3<ig5 // unique first photon from each pair
                            && ig2!=ig3 && ig2!=ig4 && ig2!=ig5 && ig2!=ig6 // clean up rest of pairs below
                            && ig3!=ig4 && ig3!=ig5 && ig3!=ig6
                            && ig4!=ig5 && ig4!=ig6
                            ){
                            System.out.println("(" + ig1 + "," + ig2 + ") , (" + ig3 + "," + ig4 + ") , (" + ig5 + "," + ig6 + ")\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can, of course, change `int n_g = 6`, but this method keeps the nested for loops and uses an if statement to deal with the pairs, which can be modified for whatever conditions you may need.

This was, ultimately, the most useful for me because the other answer, while extensive, created entirely separate classes. I needed to keep the check for 3 pairs fairly contained and shorter than what was provided in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend breaking this down into two steps.

1. Find all pairs of elements (where order matters).
2. Find all combinations of pairs (where order does not matter).

I put together a example program if you want to analyze it.

First thing I did was make a simple `Pair` class to track the pairs, compare values, and print them:

```
public class Pair {
  Integer one;
  Integer two;
  
  public Pair(Integer one, Integer two)
  {
    this.one = one;
    this.two = two;
  }
  
  public boolean hasNoMatchingValues(Pair other)
  {
    return !this.one.equals(other.one) && !this.one.equals(other.two) && !this.two.equals(other.one) && !this.two.equals(other.two);
  }
  
  public static boolean hasNoMatchingValues(Pair...values)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++)
    {
      for(int j = i + 1; j < values.length; j++)
      {
        if(!values[i].hasNoMatchingValues(values[j]))
          return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  
  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return "(" + one + ", " + two + ")";
  }
}
```

After this, I use the following code to find all pairs and then match them up into there combinations of 3:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PairCombinations
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Builds the list of unique objects
    List<Integer> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      objectList.add(i);

    //Finds all pairs and adds them to pairsList
    List<Pair> pairsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < objectList.size() - 1; i++)
    {
      for(int j = i + 1; j < objectList.size(); j++)
      {
        pairsList.add(new Pair(objectList.get(i), objectList.get(j)));
        pairsList.add(new Pair(objectList.get(j), objectList.get(i)));
      }
    }
    
    //Loop three times since you want three combinations. Can be adjusted to a recursive form.
    List<List<Pair>> allCombos = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < pairsList.size() - 2; i++)
    {
      for(int j = i + 1; j < pairsList.size() - 1; j++)
      {
        for(int k = j + 1; k < pairsList.size(); k++)
        {
          Pair one = pairsList.get(i), two = pairsList.get(j), three = pairsList.get(k);
          if(Pair.hasNoMatchingValues(one, two, three))
          {
            List<Pair> combos = new ArrayList<>();
            combos.add(one);
            combos.add(two);
            combos.add(three);
            allCombos.add(combos);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    //Print the results
    for(List<Pair> combo : allCombos)
      System.out.println(combo);
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I ran PairCombinations with i < 6 for a quick check, and in the output I saw that pair1 always had a gamma0 with combinations of the others [(0,1), (1,0), (0,2), (2,0), etc]. However, pair1 could also possibly be (3,6), for example, or have any combination of gammas that does not include the 0th. I also checked i < 8 and it had the same issue with the 0, but then also gamma1&2. This method certainly gets more combinations than mine, but not all of them.

Comment: @Illari It definitely would always have the 0th element if `i <6` since there's only 6 total elements so 3 pairs of 2 would always use all elements. Your results for `i < 8` are odd though. Let me update the code a bit. I adjusted some of the duplicate value checking for scalability. I am definitely getting results at the end such as `[(7, 2), (6, 3), (5, 4)]` with no 0th element.

Comment: @Tom Hunter, you are right about the 0th object, I keep forgetting that the loops start at 0 bc in my notes I have written down gamma1-6 and it slips my mind... This is such a fascinating answer though. Do you mind me asking what was your thought process behind this?

Comment: @Illari Isolation of process steps for sequential execution was my main thought. Figure out which steps morph the data, understand how the data will look at the end of each step, and organize each process to work with the data at that step. It's easier to think about data as what it will look like after each morph step and try to isolate working on it in that state instead of thinking about the end result which may require several morph steps to get to. Your scenario was a nice case where the Pairs can be abstracted into their own data state.